# With Type Constraint to a Base Class, the Conversion Operator of the Base Class is Called Even When the Type Parameter is the Sub Class

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

I'm troubleshooting a problem that I have recreated in a solution [here](http://www.filedropper.com/testcustomtypescast).

The issue is that I am using some custom types that can implicitly cast from string to themselves.  One of the custom types inherits from the other.

```
public class CustomType
{
    public string InnerString { get; protected set; }

    public CustomType(string s)
    {
        InnerString = s;
    }

    #region Operator Overloads
    public static implicit operator CustomType(string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return new CustomType(s);
    }
    public static implicit operator string(CustomType value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        return value.InnerString;
    }
    #endregion
}


public class SubCustomType : CustomType
{
    public SubCustomType(string s)
        : base(s)
    {
        // Nada
    }

    #region Operator Overloads
    public static implicit operator SubCustomType(string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return new SubCustomType(s);
    }
    public static implicit operator string(SubCustomType value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        return value.InnerString;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In another generic class, I rely upon the fact that the base custom type can implicitly cast from string to itself.  (The cast occurs at the line `(T)this.Rtf`.  `.Rtf` is a string.)  (The generic class is in my case a subclass of RichTextBox, since that's what I was using when I ran into this problem.)

```
public class CustomRichTextBox<T> : Forms.RichTextBox
    where T : CustomType
{
    public object GetValue()
    {
        /// This line throws:
        /// InvalidCastException
        /// Unable to cast object of type 'TestCustomTypesCast.CustomType' to type 'TestCustomTypesCast.SubCustomType'.
        return (T)this.Rtf;
    }
}

public class SubCustomRichTextBox : CustomRichTextBox<SubCustomType>
{
}
```

When I use `SubCustomRichTextBox` (an instance of the generic class that has as type argument the SUB custom type), I get an InvalidCastException at the line where I cast to `T` in `GetValue`.  What I think is going on is that in order for the compiler to be okay with the fact that I am using `T` to cast from string, it is looking at `CustomType` and seeing its cast overload.  But even when I use a subclass of `CustomType` as the actual type argument, the compiler still looks to `SubCustomType.CustomType(string s)` to perform the cast, and not at the correct `SubCustomType.SubCustomType(string s)` method.

Can anyone point me in the direction of fixing this problem?  I want to use the generic class because it would allow me to reuse the same code.  If I can't use generics, then I'll need to duplicate code in several subclasses of `CustomRichTextBox<T>`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be hard because the operator overload is static, and you're essentially trying to get a virtual behaviour.

Try this:

```
public class CustomRichTextBox<T> : Forms.RichTextBox
    where T : CustomType, new()
{
    public object GetValue()
    {
        T t = new T();
        t.InnerString = this.Rtf;
        return t;
    }
}
```

Note I've added `new()` to the type constraint. I also had to make InnerString public settable.

As an aside, you coule make the return type of `GetValue()` be `T`. That might be a nicer API.

Comment: I was hoping to represent my custom types as values as much as possible (i.e., immutable.)  So what I will do is to create a `.SetInnerString` method to make it more explicit when a user calls it.  I'm trying to figure out if there is some use of the `dynamic` type that could solve this (and whether such a solution would even be preferable!)  With regards to return type of `T` vs. `object` I agree.  This was just a hold-over from the fact that this method is actually `IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue` in my project.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: For immutability, you might want to have `.SetInnerString` throw an exception if the previous value is null (or at least fail an assertion).

Comment: That's a great idea.  In that case I can call it `.InitializeInnerString`.  Thanks.